# Discount For Specific Order Number

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, shopping-cart-price-rules, discount

We want to offer special discount for Order Number "10000900 - 10001000". Anyone who's order/purchase comes under this range will get a special discount of 40%. As far as i know magento doesn't have any feature for this. This requires code tweak in magento code. Please suggest me how can i achieve this.

Regards

Comment: Could you, please, describe for what are you going to reach with all these? I am asking because, the discount could not be applied to the order, only to the quote. The quote has no order number, it could only be reserved  “increment_id",  which will not obligatory become the order. I think you have to change your approach a little.

Comment: Thanks for stopping by, our store is reaching 1000 orders so we want to offer special discounts to purchase from 900 - 1000 order numbers. Let's say a user purchases and his order number is 901, will get the discount. We can  view this the other way that when increment_id is 900 the offer automatically gets activated through magento code.  please suggest if there is any other way of offering discount.